# Is there a way to get a BOM style output (SAP CS12) from a set of parent child relationships in R?

Tags: r, sap-erp

I am trying to download all Bill of Materials from SAP backend tables, but can only get 1 level deep for each part. So, my data is in the form of thousands of parent-child relationships of unknown depth.

```
df <- data.frame(parent = c("Finished Part A", "Finished Part A", "Part 2", "Part 3"), child = c("Part 1", " Part 2",  "Part 3", "Part 4"))
```

Is there a way to build these parent-child relationships into a tree to see which Finished Parts each child goes in to? For example, how would I be able to see that Part 3 is a part of Finished Part A.

One desired output would be in the style of the SAP CS12 view.

Currently, as I only have parent child relationships, I can only see 1 "explosion level" deep into each part.

[image]

Comment: So what's the desired output here?

Comment: A Multilevel Bill of Material that mirrors the output of the SAP CS12 view.

Comment: Or a data.tree object where I can, for example, look up "Part 3" and see that it is used in "Finished Part A"

Comment: Is that format defined somewhere? Can you give an example in your question?